# Where is the pilot flying to?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

> Barry is a pilot for the mafia. Due to his unique cargo, his employers have to give him his destination in code. Everywhere he has flown, from Edmonton to Frankfurt to Atlanta has had an international airport. After completing each job, he has always received a nice bonus. In fact, his last job paid him over 200 Grand.
>
> He started his career as a commercial pilot for Air Greenland then Express International before joining the Irish mafia. Eventually, he wants to retire to either Ethiopia, or Hawaii.

The pilot reads over the letter in his inbox a few times before entering his destination into his GPS. He frowns at the screen for a second before trying a second destination. He smiles at the map as he loads the locked briefcase into his plane and prepares to call the tower.

So, which airport is the pilot flying to?

Notes:

1. Everything you need to solve the riddle is in the blockquote section
2. I'm not sure if I chose the right tags for this, sorry in advance if the tags are incorrect or make things more confusing.

Comment: "Everything you need to solve the riddle is in the blockquote section" That's not quite true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that he is flying to

> Key West

because

> when you convert the capital letters in each sentence to numbers (A=1, B=2...), you get `245561197 817599558`. Trying a few possible locations for decimal points, and choices of where to put any `-` signs, gives `24.5561197,-81.7599558`: coordinates that exactly land on a runway at Key West International Airport.
>  [image]

Comment: congrats on reaching 100k (I'm a bit late perhaps).
Also, why did you change your profile picture?

Comment: @justhalf I've been meaning to for a while now. This is the logo I use in other places - figured the 100k-ish milestone would be a good time to make the change.