# Where is the pilot flying to? (Third Destination)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

After a close call with his [first flight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100935/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to), and with the feds still scratching their heads with his [second flight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102052/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to-second-destination), Barry once again received the instructions for his next flight from The Don of the mafia. This time, The Don sent Barry an email with a link to a website. The website itself appeared to be a recipe blog, but the design was definitely a little off, so Barry decided to view the source code.

```
<html>
<p style="color:#000033"> I apologize in advance if the recipe doesn't make 
the right number of servings. The original recipe made 10 servings, 
and I needed 16, so I converted all the measurements, but 
I drank some of the rum, and couldn't remember if I did it right, 
so I just converted it again. Tee hee! Anyway, here's the recipe!</p>

<ul>
<li style="color:#313338">2.56 boxes of yellow cake mix.</li>
<li style="color:#326533">2.56 packages of instant vanilla pudding mix.</li>
<li style="color:#343333">10.24 eggs</li>
<li style="color:#333733">1.28 cups of water</li>
<li style="color:#333263">1.28 cups canola oil</li>
<li style="color:#323032">1.28 cups rum (light or dark is fine)</li>
<li style="color:#643336">2.56 cups pecans</li></ul>

<p> And for the glaze:</p>

<ul><li style="color:#333632">3.84 sticks of butter</li>
<li style="color:#653330">0.64 cups of water</li>
<li style="color:#333033">3.84 cups of sugar</li>
<li style="color:#343331">1.92 cups of rum</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Barry was confused at first, but he looked closely at the source code and was able to pull out the relevant information, and with a few quick steps was able to translate it into a usable latitude and longitude he could input into his nav system. With that, Barry was off, flying to his third destination.

Where is Barry flying to this time?

**Hint 1:**

> Only one specific type of the content is needed to solve the puzzle, although it needs two steps to reach the final answer. The rest of the content of the puzzle (inside the block quote section) contains some clues but is not strictly necessary for the solution.

**Hint 2:**

> This is an actual recipe, although that's not really relevant. But there could be a slight clue if you figure out what amounts the original recipe most likely called for, and how the modified recipe got the new amounts. If this confuses things more for you, however, the puzzle can be solved completely without worrying about that.

Comment: Partial / Observations: rot13(Svefg, fcyvg gur urk pbybe pbqrf vagb guerr cnegf, gura pbaireg gb nfpvv. Gung tvirf lbh n pbhcyr bs guerr-qvtvg urk ahzoref, juvpu gura pna or pbairegrq gb qrpvzny ntnva. Frrzvatyl gur ynfg fgrc vf gb hfr gur zhygvcyrf bs 0.64 jvguva gur yvfg vgrzf. Gur zbfg boivbhf guvat (zhygvcyl rnpu ahzore ol vg'f pbeerfcbaqvat sybngvat cbvag, gura fhz gurz gbtrgure sbe rnpu yvfg) qbrfa'g lvryq nalguvat hfrshy. Fvapr gur ynfg yvfg vf irel fubeg, V'z nyzbfg pregnva jr unir gb gnxr gur fhz bs gur ahzoref nsgre pbairefvba. Gur zhygvcyrf ner nyfb cebonoyl abg n pbvapvqrapr...)

Comment: @LukasRotter rot13(Fyvtugyl bireguvaxvat. Ab arrq gb fcyvg, naq gur erpvcr nzbhagf nera'g qverpgyl eryngrq gb fbyivat gur chmmyr. Vg'f zber bs na rnfgre rtt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barry was flying to

> San Juan Airport

With the source, we can extract

> the colour codes and concatenate

to get:

> 000033313338326533343333333733333263323032643336333632653330333033343331

Interpreting this as

> a series of ASCII characters encoded in hexadecimal, (NUL characters ignored)

This generates

> 31382e343337332c202d36362e30303431

Interpreting this as

> a series of ASCII characters encoded in hexadecimal,

This generates

> 18.4373, -66.0041

Interpreting this as

> A latitude and longitude co-ordinate pair,

This generates

> [the location of San Juan airport](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/18%C2%B026%2714.3%22N+66%C2%B000%2714.8%22W/@18.4680759,-65.9671821,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d18.4373!4d-66.0041)

Hints to this in the flavour text include:

> "recipe" (co-ordinates) in decimal (serve 10), so converted to serve 16 (encoded in hexadecimal), but then did it twice (entire operation repeated).

This is replicated in

> The recipe, which follows the "convert from serving 10 to serving 16 twice" literally, e.g. 4 eggs becomes 10.24 eggs, and half a cup becomes 1.28 cups, etc.