# Where is the pilot flying to? (Fifth Destination)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, story

<sub>This is the fourth in a series of puzzles where the answer will always be an international airport. Previous puzzles can be found [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100935/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to), [second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102052/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to-second-destination), [third](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102652/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to-third-destination), and [fourth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104250/where-is-the-pilot-flying-to-fourth-destination). The puzzles are all independent, but follow the same general format and story.</sub>

---

No rest for the weary, Barry had just returned from his last trip when he received another note from the Don.

> So we are going to change things up a bit this time; if you have any problems feel free to call me on a secure line. Make no mistake, this is a short message that will rely on no key; a young woman might be quicker to solve this, but since you are the only person available, maybe reading the text out loud will help.
>
> Seriously, where you are *not* going is 66.644, 27.7733, but hurry up and get to where you *are* going and drop off my package.

What is the actual airport Barry is flying to this time? And for bonus points, how many of the six clues hidden in the note did you find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barry is flying to

> [O'Hare International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Hare_International_Airport)

because

> 66.644, 27.7733 can be interpreted as a SMS Phone Tap Code, i.e. executing the sequence `66644277733` on an old-school keypad like this:
> [image]
> This yields `OHARE`

I found these clues within the story:

> - "call me on a secure line" -> Hints towards phones
>  - "this is a short message" -> SMS
>  - "maybe reading the text out loud will help" -> reading "... (rely on) no key; a (young woman) ..." out loud sounds like NOKIA
>  - 'a young woman might be quicker to solve this' hints towards texting, because young women are said to be able to text faster
>  - The first letters of the three sentences spell "SMS"

Comment: The very first letters of the 3 sentences in the block spell another clue...

Comment: @Stiv Ah yes, nice catch.

Comment: The sixth and final clue is a little bit of a stretch, but it literally says "read the text", indicating it's a text message